# Jenkinsfile sh module read file line by line

Tags: while-loop, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to put up a Jenkinsfile where one of the step is to read a text file line by line and assign it to a variable. But the input to the While loop is not working.

Code Snippet:

```
dir(FilePath) {
     sh("""
          while read -r line; do 
              args+="--arg $line" 
          done < env
       """)
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign use a shell variable or pipeline variable?

Comment: I m trying to assign a shell variable

Answer (score 1):

I would use Jenkins basic step. Then you can pass it to shell or do whatever you need.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

```
dir(FilePath) {
    script {
         def file = readFile file:"file.txt"
         sh("do whatever ${file}")
    }
}
```

Comment: WorkflowScript: 55: Expected a step @ line 55, column 17.
                   def file = readFile file:"env"                        
Getting the above error while trying the above

Comment: If you are using declarative pipeline then you might need to wrap it in a script {} block

Comment: Can you please provide an example for it.

Comment: added to answer

Comment: @mettalisticpain Thanks for all you help...Much appreciated,,, 
I fixed the issue using the Shell module itself. The fix was to escape the "$" symbol in the $line variable.